# Returning images through CakePHP - good idea or bad?

Tags: image, cakephp, caching

So I'm building a site that will host lots of articles with lots of pictures in different sizes based on CakePHP. I came up with a scheme of uploading pictures through the back end, and then just saving the original. Now every time an image is needed the an image controller is called with the image id and the requested size, which is then generated and returned. Obviously this is pretty heavy, but I imagined that Cake could cache the result of the requests for me. The upside would obviously be that adding a new image size in the future would be a breeze.

But will it still be to heavy, even with caching? I would still be doing a lot of requests, even though the response would be cached. So, good idea, or bad?

Comment: Seems fine to me.  You're basically just changing when you're doing the resizing, assuming you keep your cache around for a long time.  One method is immediately on upload, so processing is front loaded.  The other is on demand, so processing is spread out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I actually found, what I feel is a very neat solution, and I would like to share it with you.

It turns out, that in a CakePHP setup, if you request an URL (say: "images/teaser/17.jpg"), the system will first check if that file exists. If it doesn't, the request will be routed through Cake to ('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'teaser', 17.jpg). I then simply set that controller up to generate and save the image, then return it.

This way, I can simply add new sizes (i.e. "teaser") later which will then be generated.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

> Now every time an image is needed the an image controller is called
>   with the image id and the requested size, which is then generated and
>   returned.

If you have only occasional visitors and don't expect to get more and want to put some stress on your CPU and fill the servers memory go for it.

Bottom line is that this is a bad solution and can crash the server in the worst case, I've actually seen this happen on live sites. Let me copy and paste some text from the documentation of my [Imagine](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin) plugin:

> You should not generate images on the fly, especially not on high
>   traffic sites, it might get your server locked up because of the
>   amount of simultaneous requests. The first request will hit your
>   server and start generating the image while others try to do that at
>   the same time, causing the site become locked up in the worst case.
>   There is no need to generate images on each request, in fact it would
>   be bad practice because it will just put load on you servers CPU and
>   consume memory.

[You can read the whole text here.](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Performance-Notes.md)

It's better to generate the needed versions directly after an image was uploaded and if other versions are needed later, generate them by a shell script.

When generating an image version give it an unique name based on the operations you applied to it:

```
my_horse.thumbnail+width-100-height+100.jpg
```

This can become pretty long and doesn't look that nice, so it's a good idea to hash the operations:

```
my_horse.e18c820f1c3da390e3d01b4fb91b0f68.jpg
```

If you want to include the original filename or not is up to you.

If you don't have to protect your images I would not pass them through Cake(PHP) at all but instead serve them directly without the php overhead.

If you look for example at flickr images you can see they are doing it very likely in a similar way:

```
https://c4.staticflickr.com/8/7544/15842932026_0cf13be2e9_n.jpg
```

I've spent some time with applications that do image processing and store a lot of files. My experience with that resulted in these two plugins:

- https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage
- https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin

They both together will do what you want in a proper and scalable way. I highly recommend you to read the documentation. I think they're pretty easy to use but they're not newbie level.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Please bear in mind though, that I'm not actually proposing to do the resizing on each request. Only the first, whereafter the cache would take over.

But the cache still requires a complete Cake request right? So I guess my worry is, whether the cache solution in itself is much heavier than simply requesting the picture directy (i.e. <img src='img/42.jpg' > )

Comment: It is logical that if you have to go through php that you get an overhead compared to just let the webserver directly send the image. You question still says that you generate your image on the fly the first time which is still bad practice. My answer explains why, 4th paragraph. "Caching" an image is simply done by creating a version of the image which my answer covers as well. How you send it is up to you, I think my answer is pretty exhaustive and covers everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you have very limited disk space but have plenty of cpu/memory this is a good option.  If you have disk space but not cpu/ram, then I wouldn't do that.

What I do for my sites that require multiple size images (this is rare) is resize the image to the 2 or 3 desired sizes and save them all. In my uploads table I save the url to the original,  resized and thumb.

Need more detail?